# Undefined symbol when using insmod

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I write a linux-kernel module, but when I run this command `insmod ./...ko`, the kernel posts an error: Undefined symbol ...

After that, I searched for a long time, all the solutions are to use `EXPORT_SYMBOL()`, so I write it in kernel codes and rebuild the kernel. Interesting things happen, the kernel says `exports duplicate symbol ... (owned by kernel)`. It seems that the symbol is exported more than once, but if so, why can I not use it before?

This is related code in my module:

```
extern struct task_struct *find_task_by_vpid(pid_t nr);
target_tsk = pid == -1 ? current : find_task_by_vpid(pid);
```

and I changed the kernel file `linux/sched.h` to this format:

```
extern struct task_struct *find_task_by_vpid(pid_t nr);
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(find_task_by_vpid);
```

Comment: please provide the sample code that you have written

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am sorry, I used to think my codes will not be helpful in this question, I have modified my question.

Comment: It might me possible that the kernel module that you have written is dependent on another kernel module which has that symbol. I suggest you run `depmod -a`.

Comment: If you need to change kernel's include file(s), then you obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Symbol exporting (`EXPORT_SYMBOL`) should be performed in a **source** file (`.c`), not in a *header* file (`.h`).

This is because exporting symbol is a *definition* of (some other) symbol, and header files a not suitable for such things.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know little about this field, I think I should improve my knowledge.